# How to print selected value from database

Tags: php

I am selecting a value from database and want to print it in the html page. I have tried this piece of code:

```
$queryreg = mysql_query("SELECT available FROM hospital WHERE h_name='$hospital' ");
 $a=    $queryreg;  
 echo   $a;
```

But the result is showing as "Resource id #7". Please help me out

Comment: check this for more info http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Comment: `mysql_*` are deprecated now. Start using `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Answer (score 1):

```
$queryreg = mysql_query("SELECT available FROM hospital WHERE h_name='$hospital' ");
    $queryreg = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryreg);
     $a=    $queryreg;  
     echo   $a['available'];
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query()` returns a resource on success. You will have to use `mysql_fetch_row` to retrieve values that returns a numerical array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead.

```
$queryreg = mysql_query("SELECT available FROM hospital WHERE h_name='$hospital' ");
if($queryreg)
{
      if(mysql_num_rows($queryreg) > 0)
      {
           $a = mysql_fetch_row($queryreg);  
           echo $a[0];
      }
      else
            echo "No records found.";
}
else
     echo "Cannot fetch records ".mysql_error();
```

In cases when there are multiple rows returning from query, you can use `mysql_fetch_array()` that fetches a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both

```
 $queryreg = mysql_query("SELECT available FROM hospital WHERE h_name='$hospital' ");
if($queryreg)
{
     if(mysql_num_rows($queryreg) > 0)
     {
          while($result = mysql_fetch_array($queryreg))
          {
               echo "<br>".$result[0];
          }
     }
     else
          echo "No records found.";
}
else
     echo "Cannot fetch records ".mysql_error();
```